# How would you convert pixel dimensions and pixel position of a div into percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a fixed pixel positioned div element that I'd like to take its size and position and convert into relative percentage. How would you do that?

Comment: Percentages are relative to the size of their containers. Without knowing the size of the container this is not possible.

Comment: Relative to the view area which is I guess window/document width/height.

Comment: OK, then get the viewport size and you can do the math.

Comment: I'm croudsourcing it ;) Seriously I was hoping someone will point me to a javascript lib that does all that malarkey for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use parentNode to access the parent, compare their sizes and voila.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var bar = document.getElementById('foo').parentNode;
console.log('Width: ' + (foo.offsetWidth / bar.offsetWidth) + '%')
```